# Interpreting Flash AS2 setInterval function

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Plz help me understand this simple Flash AS2 (Action Script 2.0) Code. In the line `setInterval(function () {blah..},5*1000);` does `function()` refers to `setinterval(the calling function)` itself or just a nameless function.

```
function wait() {      
    stop();
    var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        play();
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }, 5*1000); // stop for 5 seconds
}
wait();
```

*Can anyone put in words as to how the above code works ?*

Thanks
dk

Comment: The setInterval method only calls your function with a delay. Explanations below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setInterval` method only calls your function with a delay.

Your code calls `anonymously` a function in first argument of `setInterval` method, but this function could also be called by it's variable name with exactly the same result:

```
stop();
var myInterval = setInterval(myFunction, 5000);

function myFunction():Void {
    play();
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

If we create a pseudo setInterval fonction like following:

```
function myFunction():Void {
    trace('myFunction plays');
}

function pseudoSetInterval(func:Function, delay:Number):Void {
    this.onEnterFrame = function():Void {
        if (getTimer() > delay) {
            func();
            delete this.onEnterFrame;
        }
    }
}
```

These two invocations are équivalent:

```
var myInterval = pseudoSetInterval(myFunction, 5000);
var myInterval = pseudoSetInterval(function(){trace("a function plays");}, 5000);
```